# How to make a nested query in Realm Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have realm with lists of other realm-objects.

```
import RealmSwift

class Company: Object {
  dynamic var id = 0
  dynamic var city = 0
  dynamic var title = ""
  dynamic var address = ""
  dynamic var schedule = ""
  dynamic var workBreak = ""

  let categories = List<CompanyCategory>()
  let phones = List<CompanyPhone>()
  let sites = List<CompanySite>()
  let emails = List<CompanyEmail>()
  let services = List<CompanyService>()
  let branches = List<CompanyBranche>()

}

class CompanyCategory: Object {
  dynamic var id = 0
  dynamic var name = ""
}
```

So, I have category id and I want to see which companies is refer to this category. Company may have several categories.

I find [solution](http://goo.gl/p2HWkZ) in Java and it works in my android app. Can somebody help me to write right predication? 
Sorry for my bad english (:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Realm Swift uses Cocoa's NSPredicate to represent queries. You can find some examples of the supported syntax in the [Filtering section of the Realm Swift documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#filtering), and more information about the syntax on [NSPredicate Cheatsheet](https://realm.io/news/nspredicate-cheatsheet/). From those two documents you'll arrive at something like the following for your query:

```
realm.objects(Company).filter("ANY categories.id = %@", id)
```